Scraping Youtube video
I want to scrape a YouTube video using the requests module, but after I obtain the video and audio links, the request's status code is always 403 or I get no response. If I don't add 'Content-Length' in the headers, the status code is 403, but if I do add it, there is no response.
import requests
import re
import json
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LkIUfpX-k0'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "zh-TW,zh;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://www.youtube.com/",
}
cookies = {
    "YSC": "e2LSE4IOe5g",
    "VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE": "BHEJagtnezo",
    "VISITOR_PRIVACY_METADATA": "CgJUVxIEGgAgag%3D%3D",
    "PREF": "f4=4000000&tz=Asia.Taipei",
    "GPS": "1"
}
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
ans = re.findall(
    'var ytInitialPlayerResponse = (.*?);var', response.text)[0]
ans = json.loads(ans)
audio = ans['streamingData']['adaptiveFormats'][0]['url']
headers['Content-length'] = ans['streamingData']['adaptiveFormats'][-2]['contentLength']
video = requests.post(url=audio, headers=headers,
                     cookies=cookies)
print(video.status_code)
if video.status_code == 200:
    with open('video.mp3', mode='wb')as file:
        file.write(video. Content)

I have tried to add all of the data in the json file as headers but the status code will be 403 and if I only use Referer, User-Agent and Content-Length as headers, it will be no response.

Passing Cookies is not enough. YouTube needs your PO Token so that it'll decipher the video url but one problem i encountered is that the deciphered url is only valid once and can't be reused.

well, after I asked the question, I have kept trying to scrape it and I found that there are some payload I didn't send it. One is cpn, and the other is rn. I think cpn is generate by base.js and rn is the sequence of data. So I think I should find how cpn and rn are generated.

The yt_dlp library in Python allows you to download both video and audio. Therefore, I prefer the yt_dlp method.
# video

import yt_dlp

while True:
    url = input("Enter the YouTube video URL: ")

    ydl_opts = {
        "format": "bestvideo+bestaudio/best",
        "outtmpl": "%(title)s.%(ext)s",
        "merge_output_format": "mp4",
    }

    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])


# audio

import yt_dlp

while True:
    url = input("Enter the YouTube video URL: ")

    ydl_opts = {
        "format": "mp3/bestaudio/best",
        "outtmpl": "%(title)s.%(ext)s",
        # ℹ️ See help(yt_dlp.postprocessor) for a list of available Postprocessors and their arguments
        "postprocessors": [
            {
                "key": "FFmpegExtractAudio",
                "preferredcodec": "mp3",
            }
        ],
    }

    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])


Thank you to tell me such a convenient library, I will try to use it (but I think I will keep trying scrape it by myself. Actually, I used to use pytube to scrape the video, but after a few months, the library isn't work anymore. I am afraid of the library will not able to work someday, so I will try to learn how to scrape it as more as possible)
